# tensor product of projective irreducible modules

Tags: gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory

Let $G$ be a $p$-solvable group and $M_{1}$, $M_{2}$ are finite
dimensional projective irreducible $kG$-modules, where the
characteristic of $k$ is $p$. Is the tensor product
$M_{1}\bigotimes_{k}M_{2}$ a semisimple $kG$-module?

Comment: Do such modules always exist ? If G is a p-group then $k$ is the only simple (=irrecducible) kG-module, but it isn't projective. 

Comment: You'd need a simple projective for this, and this occurs when there is a block of defect zero, no?

Comment: @Ralph, Mariano: I don't know the motivation for the question, but the set-up here is very special and won't apply for instance to a `$p$`-group.   Simple projectives do come up in the setting of blocks of defect 0 in Brauer's theory.

Answer (score 3):

I found the following counterexample using Magma. The group $S_3$ has a 2-dimensional absolutely irreducible module $M$ over the field of order 2, which is projective. The tensor square $T$ of $M$ is isomorphic to the direct sum of $M$ and an indecomposable 2-dimensional module with two composition factors equal to the trivial module, so $T$ is not semisimple.

Comment: @Derek: Isn't the other indecomposable here just the projective cover of the trivial module? This example looks like a degenerate version of what usually happens in the `$p$`-modular representation theory of `$\mathrm{SL}(2,p)$` for odd `$p$`: the Steinberg module of dimension `$p$` is simple and projective, while tensoring it with the 2-dimensional natural module gives an indecomposable projective with three composition factors.  For `$p=2$` this would break up into your direct sum. (But for odd `$p$` the group is not `$p$`-solvable.) 

Comment: @Jim: Yes, that's right! The other summand is the projective cover of the trivial module. I was just looking quickly for the smallest counterexample, and didn't have to look far!

Answer (score 3):

It is, if the sum of dimensions is less then $p+2$, by Serre's Theorem (Sur la semi-simplicité des produits tensoriels de représentations de groupes).

Comment: I think that should be "less than $p+2$". My counterexample has $p=2$, with two modules of duimension 2.

Comment: @BB: Following Serre's 1994 Invent. Math. paper, Jantzen and then McNinch worked out significant refinements for finite groups of Lie type.  This is summarized with references in 12.12 of my 2006 LMS Lecture Note Series 326, *Modular representations of finite groups of Lie type*.  By now the bounds are almost definitive, but Lie rank 1 is tricky for all primes.  A basic constraint comes from the fact that tensoring in the defining characteristic with a Steinberg module yields a projective module.   